# What kind of html/layout is that? columns/table?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, tabular

I'm pretty new in coding, my question is how to make this kind of layout?

https://www.carstensens-tehandel.dk/te-the.html

Is it possible just html/css ?
What to type to find tutorial about it? Because on w3 I just found columns.

My purpose is to re-create for a school project a page of a webshop.

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer:** Yes, you can make this site with just html/css.

**The long answer:** You can make any site with those basic front-end languages. As HTML is structure and CSS is style. If you have the time and patience to "hard-code" every bit of information, content, and assets into your code then this is achievable. There are other languages that can pick up the heavy burden of content management such as PHP, or even content management systems such as Wordpress, which offer out-of-box solutions. But the approach of your development heavily depends on how simple to complex you want your website to be.

**Recommendation:** Google is your friend, along with W3Schools, Tree House, Code academy, and my personal favorite Google Inspector tool. Do your research my friend and dive deep into front-end languages like HTML, CSS, and JS to start. You will not find a "Step by Step" or "Tutorial based" answer to your questions here.

Comment: ok cool thank you for your answers i'll make make researches then :)